# Excel 2016 and ODBC driver for PostgreSQL

Tags: excel, macos, postgresql, odbc

I am trying to connect Excel 2016 for Mac (on OS X El Capitan, 10.11) to a PostgreSQL database through ODBC connection; so I downloaded the drivers, specifically [Actual Open source Databases](http://www.actualtech.com/product_opensourcedatabases.php).

I set everything up, test the connection successfully, but as soon as I try to save the settings, Excel crashes.

Should I try to re-install Excel? Any advice is strongly appreciated!

(I know already, Excel sucks ... but I still need to establish the connection)
Best, Vincenzo

Answer (score 2):

Excel 2016 has issues (much more substantial in October 2015, but still present in November 2016).  It's really not ready for prime time.  Excel 2011 is a better bet, as things stand.

If you're stuck with Excel 2016, update to the latest [iODBC](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/Downloads#Mac_OS_X) (3.52.12, as of July 2016), *create* your DSN (System DSN recommended; User DSN may work for you) in `iODBC Administrator.app` (found in `/Applications/iODBC/`), and then *use* it with Excel.

([iODBC](http://iodbc.org/), produced by [my employer, OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), is the open source ODBC driver manager Apple has bundled into OS X since 10.2, but Apple remains several years behind the current iODBC version.)

Comment: It's now 2021, has the situation changed?  I googled around and it seems people just gave up.

Comment: @HenriettaMartingale -- Many things have changed.  I don't know what you're taking to be a sign that "people just gave up".  MS Excel and Office 2016 have progressed to 2019 and 365; iODBC is now 3.52.15; macOS is 11.x on x86_64 or M1; and on and on and on.  As always, the best troubleshooting advice for all of these is to make sure the latest versions are installed across the board.  After that, I would suggest you start a new question or thread, if you're still running into trouble.

Comment: Yes, but I'm still on excel 2016.  I'm fine with it though.  I bought a driver, life's too short.